# Why do I not need `ref mut` when pattern matching on a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, destructuring

I'm struggling with destructuring/auto dereferencing.

I have a snippet of code, which works and I kind of see why - `a` is mutable and we pass a mutable reference to `match`. In the `match` statement we have a pattern which expects a mutable reference, and we take inner variables which are references to avoid moving them out.

```rust
let x = vec![1, 2];
let y = vec![3, 4];
let mut a = (x, y);
match &mut a {
    &mut (ref aa, ref bb) => {}
}
```

I'm struggling to see why the following pattern works. I expect the pattern not to match to begin with, but it matches and `aa` and `bb` are both mutable references (no need for `ref mut`). I feel that this is some auto dereferencing at play:

```rust
match &mut a {
    (aa, bb) => {
        aa[0] = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that this is some auto dereferencing at play?

I wouldn't call it "auto" dereferencing because your intention to dereference the matched value is made explicit as part of your destructuring pattern. But yes, when you match a mutable reference against a pattern with a mutable reference it's the same as dereferencing the matched value. You can see this in action in this simpler code example:

```rust
fn main() {
    for num in &[1, 2, 3] {
        // type of `num` inside loop is &i32
        // explicit deref required for equality check
        if *num == 3 {
            println!("found 3");
        }
    }
    
    // implicit deref in destructuring pattern
    for &num in &[1, 2, 3] {
        // type of `num` inside loop is i32
        // no need for explicit deref operation now
        if num == 3 {
            println!("found 3");
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c968954c69a4999ab721e11fb46ed9df)